# HyBirdAuth Twitch Subscriber?

Tags: php, wordpress, session, hybridauth

I've written my own function to check if a the user is subscribed, But i did this using my own authentication method, How can i use hybirdauth to use my function to check if the login in user is subscriber? I know i can get the access token by doing Hybrid_Provider_Adapter::getAccessToken(). My function returns a simple httpd 200 if subscriber, any other value isn't important. My main question is where can i insert my function, where do i call to check for the http code. I have add user_subscribe as an additional scope which works.

```
    public function subcheck($access_token){
    $username = $this->authenticated_user($access_token);
    $url="https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/users/" . $username . "/subscriptions/".$channel;
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/vnd.twitchtv.v3+json', 'Authorization: OAuth '.$access_token));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0);

    // Execute
    $result=curl_exec($ch);
    $httpdStatus = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    // Will dump a beauty json :3
    //var_dump(json_decode($result, true));
    return $httpdStatus;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Change the public scope to

   ```
   public $scope = "user_read user_subscriptions";
   ```

2.Change the getUserProfile to below, this will check if user is a sub, if user isnt a sub it will stop the script and redirect page.

```
    function getUserProfile()
{

    $data = $this->api->api( "user" );

    if ( ! isset( $data->name ) ){
        throw new Exception( "User profile request failed! {$this->providerId} returned an invalid response.", 6 );
    }

    $access_token = $this->api->access_token;
    $username = $data->display_name;
    $channel= "Twitch_Channel_Here"
    $url="https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/users/" . $username . "/subscriptions/".$channel."";
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/vnd.twitchtv.v3+json', 'Authorization: OAuth '.$access_token));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0);
    // Execute
    $result=curl_exec($ch);
    $httpdStatus = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    //Check if Sub?? 200 == Sub?
    if ($httpdStatus == "200") {
                //Do Nothing
                echo 'SUB';
            }
            else {
        //if not a sub then well... ...
        header("Location: http://google.com/nonsub.jpg"); /* Redirect browser */
        exit();
    }
    $this->user->profile->identifier    = $data->_id;
    $this->user->profile->displayName   = $data->display_name;
    $this->user->profile->photoURL      = $data->logo;
    $this->user->profile->profileURL    = "http://www.twitch.tv/" . $data->name;
    $this->user->profile->email         = $data->email;

    if( ! $this->user->profile->displayName ){
        $this->user->profile->displayName = $data->name;
    }
```